# APOD two colliding black holes article of 9-8-20

Tags: cosmology

Why are both axes spinning the same way before colliding? Conversely, in order to collide both spins must be the same?

Comment: The referenced [Astronomy Picture of  the Day](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html) is [this one](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2009/GW190521_Virgo_1667.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

The orbital and spin angular momenta are mostly decoupled until the final moments of the merger. There is no physics that prevents the spins being (nearly) aligned or anti-aligned.

The relative orientations (and magnitude) of the spin vectors compared with the orbital angular momentum is presumably telling us something about the formation of these systems in their pre-merger phase.